# How can a MS Teams Bot find the participant list of the personal chat its Messaging Extension was clicked from?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

We have a Teams bot with a messaging extension which is available in personal scope.  User A adds the bot in their Teams client. Thereafter, the messaging extension is available in any chat conversation the user A is participating in.

When User A clicks on the messaging extension while in a one to one chat with User B, we would like the messaging extension to return search results based on who User B is. Is this possible?  It is trivial to find who User A is and most sample code available customize search results based on User A identity, but how do we find who User B is so we can return search results based on User B.

The only identifying information on the bot end is the conversation id.  Will the Graph return information with roster on this id?  Under what circumstances and with what permissions can we discover user B identity?  (We dont need to message User B, we just need to know who they are)

(User A and B are in the same tenant.  User B may or may not have added the Bot.   User B could also be another Bot)

[edited] User-Agent: [Microsoft-SkypeBotApi (Microsoft-BotFramework/3.0)] Content-Length: [1094] X-Forwarded-For: [XXXXX] X-Forwarded-Proto: [https] X-Forwarded-Port: [443] ContextId: [tcid=23586133321391XXXXX, server=BL2PEPF0000XXXXX] MS-CV: [Ynu79aRrskq54dj/XXXXXXX.1]  {"name":"composeExtension/query","type":"invoke","timestamp":"2020-04-17T19:52:10.007Z","localTimestamp":"2020-04-18T01:22:10.007+05:30","id":"f:2358613332139124116","channelId":"msteams","serviceUrl":"https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/","from":{"id":"29:1w4_XXXXX","name":"XXX YY","aadObjectId":"ZZZZZZZ"},"conversation":{"conversationType":"personal","tenantId":"ZZZZZZZZZ","id":"a:xxxxxx_b"},"recipient":{"id":"28:a0caff76-192c-4898-xxxx-ttttttt","name":"CompanyTeamsBridge"},"entities":[{"locale":"en-US","country":"US","platform":"Windows","type":"clientInfo"}],"channelData":{"tenant":{"id":"3f2fc557-7192-4d4a-9793-XXXXXXXXX"},"source":{"name":"compose"}},"value":{"commandId":"getPersonalMessage","parameters":[{"name":"initialRun","value":"true"}],"queryOptions":{"skip":0,"count":25}},"locale":"en-US"}

Comment: Yes, you could fetch the roster inside a Message Extension. You would need to do a justInTimeIntsllation of the app within that conversation to fetch the roster. Please go through this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/messaging-extension-v3/create-extensions?tabs=typescript#request-to-install-your-conversational-bot) and let me know if you need any help.

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT Thanks.  It works when the Message Extension is added to a conversation between 2 users.   Is it likewise expected to work when the user is talking to a different Teams bot?  In this case, it appears the bot with the messaging extension can not be added to the conversation (and therefore can not get the roster).   Related: Can two bots we part of a conversation with a user?

Comment: No. This isn't possible. A bot cannot have a conversation with other bot and hence fetching roster in conversation between two bots does not work.